# Measure similarity between different images?

Tags: image-processing, similarity

I want to compare the similarity between different images. I know there are serval methods to make comparisons, but in my case all images are preprocessed by resnet, so my data set looks like (N,1000) where N indicates the number of images and 1000 is a vector standing for features of each image.

How can I measure the similarity among different images? Can I use Euclidean distance to measure it?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of images are they? Grayscale? Binary masks? What characteristics do you want to take into account? Based on your initial post it is hard to grasp what you want to accomplish in detail.

If you want to measure the exact similarity you can use the [Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient).